# ORDER BY, SELECT with UNION sort difficulty

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have difficulty using the keyword UNION in my SQL request,
I need to sort my result by column which is not displayed by a SELECT,

```
    DECLARE @search0 varchar(30);

SET @search0 = 'joll'


SELECT c.CdCnd AS n, FORMAT(c.ModifieLe, 'd', 'fr-FR') AS Modifié, c.Nom+' '+c.prenom AS 'Nom Complet', c.TelMobile AS 'Tel. Mob', c.SuiviPar AS 'Suivi par', a.LibAction AS 'à faire', c.Remuneration AS Rémunération, p.LibPrio AS Priorité, c.disponibilite AS Disponibilité, c.MotCleTech AS MCTech, c.MotCleFct AS MCFonc, c.MotCleEnt AS MCEnt, c.Details AS 'Détails', c.DateDispo AS DTDispo, c.Mobilite AS Mobilité
FROM Candidat c
LEFT JOIN TypAction a 
    ON c.CdAction = a.CdAction
LEFT JOIN TypPriorite p 
    ON c.CdPrio = p.CdPrio  
WHERE  (  ( Nom LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR prenom LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleTech LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleFct LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleEnt LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  )  ) 

    UNION 

SELECT c.CdCnd AS n, FORMAT(c.ModifieLe, 'd', 'fr-FR') AS Modifié, c.Nom+' '+c.prenom AS 'Nom Complet', c.TelMobile AS 'Tel. Mob', c.SuiviPar AS 'Suivi par', a.LibAction AS 'à faire', c.Remuneration AS Rémunération, p.LibPrio AS Priorité, c.disponibilite AS Disponibilité, c.MotCleTech AS MCTech, c.MotCleFct AS MCFonc, c.MotCleEnt AS MCEnt, c.Details AS 'Détails', c.DateDispo AS DTDispo, c.Mobilite AS Mobilité
FROM Candidat c
LEFT JOIN TypAction a 
    ON c.CdAction = a.CdAction
LEFT JOIN TypPriorite p 
    ON c.CdPrio = p.CdPrio  
WHERE  ( 1 = 2  OR  c.CdCnd = '3' OR  c.CdCnd = '48' OR  c.CdCnd = '16' )

ORDER BY Modifié DESC
```

Here, i need to sort my all result by DateTime with the column c.ModifieLe,
But, with the UNION restriction, I am able to use this column without displaying it, and i need to FORMAT my date in 'fr-FR',

So, i use "Modifié" to sort my result, but this sort like a varchar type...

I need to FORMAT my DateTime in french cultur et keep it to  Date Type.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First apply UNION and Then sort them:

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.CdCnd AS n, 
        c.ModifieLe, 
        c.Nom+' '+c.prenom AS 'Nom Complet', 
        c.TelMobile AS 'Tel. Mob', 
        c.SuiviPar AS 'Suivi par', 
        a.LibAction AS 'à faire', 
        c.Remuneration AS Rémunération, 
        p.LibPrio AS Priorité, 
        c.disponibilite AS Disponibilité, 
        c.MotCleTech AS MCTech, 
        c.MotCleFct AS MCFonc, 
        c.MotCleEnt AS MCEnt, 
        c.Details AS 'Détails', 
        c.DateDispo AS DTDispo, 
        c.Mobilite AS Mobilité
    FROM Candidat c
    LEFT JOIN TypAction a 
        ON c.CdAction = a.CdAction
    LEFT JOIN TypPriorite p 
        ON c.CdPrio = p.CdPrio  
    WHERE  (  ( Nom LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR prenom LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleTech LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleFct LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleEnt LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  )  ) 

    UNION 

    SELECT 
        c.CdCnd AS n, 
        c.ModifieLe, 
        c.Nom+' '+c.prenom AS 'Nom Complet', 
        c.TelMobile AS 'Tel. Mob', 
        c.SuiviPar AS 'Suivi par', 
        a.LibAction AS 'à faire', 
        c.Remuneration AS Rémunération, 
        p.LibPrio AS Priorité, 
        c.disponibilite AS Disponibilité, 
        c.MotCleTech AS MCTech, 
        c.MotCleFct AS MCFonc, 
        c.MotCleEnt AS MCEnt, 
        c.Details AS 'Détails', 
        c.DateDispo AS DTDispo, 
        c.Mobilite AS Mobilité
    FROM Candidat c
    LEFT JOIN TypAction a 
        ON c.CdAction = a.CdAction
    LEFT JOIN TypPriorite p 
        ON c.CdPrio = p.CdPrio  
    WHERE  ( 1 = 2  OR  c.CdCnd = '3' OR  c.CdCnd = '48' OR  c.CdCnd = '16' )
)
SELECT
    [n],    
    FORMAT([ModifieLe], 'd', 'fr-FR') AS Modifié,  
    [Nom Complet], 
    [Tel. Mob], 
    [Suivi par], 
    [à faire], 
    [Rémunération], 
    [Priorité], 
    [Disponibilité], 
    [MCTech], 
    [MCFonc], 
    [MCEnt], 
    [Détails], 
    [DTDispo], 
    [Mobilité]
FROM T ORDER BY CAST(ModifieLe AS DATETIME) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ORDER BY should be

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME,Modifié,103) DESC
```

Comment: I agree, with a side note that this causes a bit of extra work: first formatting, and then parsing what was just formatted. If that causes problems then the UNION should first be sorted without any formatting using a sub-query, and after that the FORMAT can be done on the result of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
select * from(
SELECT c.CdCnd AS n, FORMAT(c.ModifieLe, 'd', 'fr-FR') AS Modifié, c.Nom+' '+c.prenom AS 'Nom Complet', c.TelMobile AS 'Tel. Mob', c.SuiviPar AS 'Suivi par', a.LibAction AS 'à faire', c.Remuneration AS Rémunération, p.LibPrio AS Priorité, c.disponibilite AS Disponibilité, c.MotCleTech AS MCTech, c.MotCleFct AS MCFonc, c.MotCleEnt AS MCEnt, c.Details AS 'Détails', c.DateDispo AS DTDispo, c.Mobilite AS Mobilité
FROM Candidat c
LEFT JOIN TypAction a 
    ON c.CdAction = a.CdAction
LEFT JOIN TypPriorite p 
    ON c.CdPrio = p.CdPrio  
WHERE  (  ( Nom LIKE '%%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR prenom LIKE '%%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleTech LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleFct LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  OR MotCleEnt LIKE '%' + @search0 + '%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AI  )  ) 

    UNION 

SELECT c.CdCnd AS n, FORMAT(c.ModifieLe, 'd', 'fr-FR') AS Modifié, c.Nom+' '+c.prenom AS 'Nom Complet', c.TelMobile AS 'Tel. Mob', c.SuiviPar AS 'Suivi par', a.LibAction AS 'à faire', c.Remuneration AS Rémunération, p.LibPrio AS Priorité, c.disponibilite AS Disponibilité, c.MotCleTech AS MCTech, c.MotCleFct AS MCFonc, c.MotCleEnt AS MCEnt, c.Details AS 'Détails', c.DateDispo AS DTDispo, c.Mobilite AS Mobilité
FROM Candidat c
LEFT JOIN TypAction a 
    ON c.CdAction = a.CdAction
LEFT JOIN TypPriorite p 
    ON c.CdPrio = p.CdPrio  
WHERE  ( 1 = 2  OR  c.CdCnd = '3' OR  c.CdCnd = '48' OR  c.CdCnd = '16' )
)
ORDER BY Modifié DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can SET like this `{SET DATEFORMAT { format_column | varchar_column }}`
 and for sorting you can use having clause in the where condition. Instead of `UNION` you can use OR condition in the where clause in First Query.